# Can't upload picture to directory in codeiginter framework

Tags: codeigniter

Below is my code.  I am trying to save a picture in a directory. The data goes to the database correct but the directory is empty. Below is my control code please check and help me.

```
public function addMakupTips()
{

    $this->load->model('makuptipsmodel');


        //Uploading data

        $config = array(
        'upload_path'   => "./makupimages",
        'allowed_types' => 'jpg|png|jpeg',
        'overwrite'     => TRUE,  
        'encrypt_name' => TRUE,                     
    );

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    $files = $_FILES['uploads'];

    foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $filename) {
        $_FILES['uploads[]']['name']     = $files['name'][$key];
        $_FILES['uploads[]']['type']     = $files['type'][$key];
        $_FILES['uploads[]']['tmp_name'] = $files['tmp_name'][$key];
        $_FILES['uploads[]']['error']    = $files['error'][$key];
        $_FILES['uploads[]']['size']     = $files['size'][$key];

        $config['file_name'] = $filename;

        $this->upload->initialize($config);

                $uploads[] = $this->upload->data();
                $array = array(
                    'name'      => $this->input->post('name'),
                    'category'      => $this->input->post('category'),
                    'title'      => $this->input->post('title'),
                    'poetry'      => $this->input->post('poetry'),
                    'keywords'      => $this->input->post('keywords'),
                    'image'  => $_FILES['uploads[]']['name']

                );

                $this->makuptipsmodel->addData($array);


    redirect(base_url() . 'admin/makuptips/index/' . $record_id);

        //Uploading end
        }


}
```

In above code, I am trying to save a complete form data in a database with a picture.  This is my form screen short

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpAOy.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent copy and pasting from the user guide, you should go and have a read of it again...

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html#the-controller

Your code appears to be missing the do_upload call...

```
$this->upload->do_upload() // See the user guide
```